# How do i create a mysql-user that can dump the database structure but not access the data?

Tags: backup, mysql, database-backups

I want to write a `mysqldump` command that dumps the structure of all tables in my database, but not the data in them, into a file (using the `--no-data`-flag).

I will need a user that has access to the database but i don't want the user to be able to make any changes to the database, or select any data. I only want it to be able to show the stucture ( like you do with `show create table Table;`).

Is this possible? How do i create this user?

Edit: I created a user with just the `Create`-permission to the table. Running `mysqldump` gives me this error:

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `Table`': SELECT command denied to user 'dump_structure'@'localhost' for table 'Table' (1142)

Does this mean that i need to give mysqldump access to all my data in all my tables? Even if it doesn't need to select it?

Comment: doubt it's possible. mysqldump needs "select" privs to access a table, and there's no mysql priv that allows for viewing schema only: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html

Comment: @MarcB There is some way of limiting what you can select though. You can limit on tables and on columns? Maybe it is possible to grant permissions to all tables but no columns in those tables?

Comment: no idea, but go ahead and try it. not sure how mysql would react to a table where you can't read any columns.